# VARCHAR (10 CHAR) in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

In my Entity Framework project I am trying to create an Oracle table that uses a column with the datatype VARCHAR2 (10 CHAR).

The following code creates a column with the type VARCHAR2 (10 BYTE), and I cannot find a solution to change the BYTE into a CHAR.

```
builder.Property(p => p.MyColumn)
    .HasColumnName("MY_COLUMN")
    .IsUnicode(false)
    .HasMaxLength(10)
    .IsRequired(false);
```

Comment: What happens if you use `IsUnicode(true)`? You are presumably specifying single-byte characters with the code you currently have. So 10 bytes is 10 characters. I don't really use Oracle so I'm just guessing.

Comment: I think in Oracle, there is no distinction between Unicode and non-Unicode character sets for `VARCHAR2` columns. The `.IsUnicode(false)` configuration is typically used for databases like SQL Server where there is a clear distinction between Unicode and non-Unicode character data types (`nvarchar vs varchar`).

Comment: When you specify the type with IsUnicode(true) you get a VARCHAR, when you leave it out, you get a NVARCHAR

Comment: As a workaround you may try to execute `alter session set NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS = 'CHAR'` after connection  is established or use `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` environment variable. UPD: there's a native way to set this via [OracleGlobalization](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/odpnt/GlobalizationProperties.html#GUID-8F13BEF7-283B-4468-82A4-7E293911DE45) class

Comment: Before doing such stuff, I want to see if there is some kind of native way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the column type explicitly using the `.HasColumnType()` method.

```
builder.Property(p => p.MyColumn)
    .HasColumnName("MY_COLUMN")
    .HasColumnType("VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)")
    .IsRequired(false);
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick. Thanks!
I thought I tried your solution, but I left the HasMaxLength() method in my call and this seems to have broken it.